# Docker build fails with Signature failures from ubuntu and debian repos

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

Using:

- Host OS: Ubuntu `VERSION="20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)"`
- `Docker version 20.10.17`.

Current simple `Dockerfile`:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils curl nodejs postgresql-client
```

Running the following:

```
docker build --tag my-ubuntu .
```

Docker then started throwing the following errors since Friday:

```
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease' is not signed.
```

- I've checked my root partition to make sure it has room already.
- I've ran `docker system df` and pruned and cleaned that up as well.

I'm out of ideas why this is happening.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by running the following in the end:

```
docker build --network=host --tag my-dum-ubuntu .
```

Not sure why this was needed, never had to do it before. But, that's docker for you I guess.

For the `docker-compose` users and my builds with that tool I had to add the following to whatever service was using `apt`:

```
web:
  ...
  network_mode: "host"
  ...
```

And that got passed the `apt` commands, of course now my `curl` won't work so on to the next error.